# sudo apt-get update command not working what i do

Tags: command-line, software-sources

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and I tried running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

But I get the below error:

```
E: Malformed line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include what line 59 says in the `/etc/apt/sources.list` it points to.

Comment: Did you edit that file before? Could you edit your post to contain it?

Comment: Mine `/etc/apt/sources.list` is 57 lines long so you probably added something to it.

Comment: And again: Post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terminal, run `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and scroll down to line 59. Put a `#` before whatever's listed there (Thanks, Jacajack), save it and then run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Or add `#` before it. It's just safer.

Comment: @Jacajack Before what?

Comment: Before that line in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, to comment it out.

Comment: No problem, Zacharee. ;)